# iOS: How to load a portion of a larger file for uploading?

Tags: ios, ios5, nsstream, alasset

I am working with large instances of ALAsset and I am trying to split the asset up into smaller chunks for uploading.

What is a good approach to split a large file up into smaller chunks without loading the entire file into memory?

Comment: Read to buffer, write buffer to web request, repeat

Comment: Thanks for your response Cole. I realize that this is trivial for most developers, but could you elaborate (perhaps with a simplified code snippet) in an answer. This way I can accept the answer and mark the question as answered.

Comment: sorry, but I don't code in obj-c, only c++ and c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this in a text editor but it should compile. NSFileHandle is a thin wrapper around the UNIX file utilities.

```
    #define CHUNK_SIZE 2048

        NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFIleHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:<the file path as a 

string>];

    while(YES) {
        NDSata *chunk = [fh readDataOfLength:CHUNK_SIZE];

        NSUInteger length = [chunk length];
        if(length == 0) break; // done

        // send the data
    }
    fh = nil; // under arc this releases the object
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, David. I was also thinking in the direction of NSFileHandle. I will definitely give this a try.